# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my Printer anymore

Tags: 12.04, printing

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a `HP Officejet Pro 8000` (network) Printer. I've never experienced  any problems with it until yesterday. The day before yesterday I was printing something at it worked.

Yesterday I wanted to print something but couldn't find the printer in Ubuntu. I went to "Printing" and it said `"Printing service not available. Start this service on this computer or connect to another server"` the button `"Start Service"` is not click-able, though. When I click on `"connect"` it says `"CUPS Server:"` and the only option is `"localhost"` if I hit connect an error occurs saying `"CUPS Server error: there was an error during the CUPS operation: 'failed to connect to another server'"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `sudo service cups restart` then try again. If not, reinstall `cups` using `apt-get`. Then try again with `sudo service cups restart`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Now my printer got recognized. Printing still doesn't work though. If I go to 'printing' my printer is there but there's also an exclamation mark in a red circle. Right click -> properties: under 'Printer State' it says 'Stopped - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups" not available: No such file or directory'

Comment: Install the HP printer drivers - see [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html). You may also need to reinstall cups, or `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Does it work while connected via USB? There is a manual - http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01659070.pdf

Comment: Alright, I installed hplip, updated and upgraded. Now the exclamation mark is gone. So everything looks normal. But it still doesn't print when I tell it to. I tried connecting it via usb but it didnt work. That was before I installed hplip, though. I can try again if I get the cable back.

Comment: A friend of mine fixed it. Under properties -> Location he put in the ip address and enabled it.

Comment: You can add it as an answer then. You can find the IP address usually by running something like this - `nmap -A 192.168.1.1-15`- this example will identify the users of all IP addresses between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.15. You may have to install it first - `sudo apt-get install nmap`. You can then find the printer's IP address. As the IP address may change when the modem is restarted, you can run nmap afterwards to check if the IP address has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-daemon
```

which starts a printing server that takes care of printing for us.

I started getting this after installing libcups2, I think it uninstalled the above package.

A symptom of this is that the `sudo service cups start` should fail as the package is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to System., Printers from the Application Menu 
Position your cursor on the the HP Printer, right-click and Delete it
Now, re-Add the printer

I had the same same "missing" file message, and this worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple

```
sudo service cups restart
```

solves the problem.

I faced this problem and solved this way.